How can I work at vast scale differences (human-scale to planetary-scale) within one blender file?
I have the following problem: I want to create a scene that contains vast differences in scale. Particularly, I want a camera that flies from human-scale on the surface of the planet (picturing full figures, with the most close-up shot being of two hands shaking) all the way out to space. The issue is that if I attempt to display an earth sized object (and some sci-fi elements like a huge space station in orbit etc.) in the same scene as some characters interacting on a human-scale, then things get very whack on either side of the scale spectrum. I know how to adjust the clipping distances of the cameras and the viewport, but even that has its limits.

With the clip start set to 100 m  and the clip end set to the absolute maximum (99999997952 m), the earth sized UV sphere looks fine. However, obviously I cannot have a clip start of 100 m if I want to render human-scale character interactions.  

If I decrease the clip start to 1 m, then things get whack on the earth-scale sphere. The flickering of the surface is only part of the problem, the other issue is that the earth totally disappears if looked at from certain angles. That happens even if I raise the clip start to 100 m (here a short video screen recording to demonstrate that last particular quirk: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ePBreBtRrKo2wvVzArU-3DqcV_Y9FfgY/view?usp=drivesdk).
Apart from that, navigating between the two scales is also tedious, I often find my viewport pointing at empty space, so I am constantly centering my view back to the world origin just to then attempt to navigate the viewport camera "back up to space", if you will, hoping that I don't get lost in nothingness on the way again.
All this makes working at these different scales extremely cumbersome. How would you guys resolve this issue?

The "flickering" is called Depth Buffer Glitch or Z-Buffer Glitch and it is a problem in 3D software generally, not limited to Blender. The z-buffer is basically depth information stored as kind of greyscale heightmap. The problem is when its range is too far from start to end, the accuracy is lost because of floating point errors. That is very simplified and I'm not an expert for the technical side, so please forgive me. A best method as workaround I do not know right now, and I guess this comes down to (not objectively correct) opinion-based answers, which are usually off-topic here.

By the way: very low Start values are usually responsible or more visible as glitches in Perspective view while very high End values produce glitches in Orthographic view. I can only recommend switching the values depending on what you need while working on it, either for working on small objects or working on large objects. These glitches do not appear in the render afterwards.

Hello, this is a very common problem, and most if not all ways to circumvent it are not the way you're going about it. I suggest taking a look at these 2 videos that explain thoroughly what's at stake here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbY0mBXKKT0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7axImc1sxa0 TLDR : The world should be moving, not the camera-man
